# Add data to database if data is unique

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, duplicates

Here I have an php PDO code for INSERT data to database:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

            try {        
                $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
                $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO track_aktivnosti (datum, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['datum']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['id_akt']);
                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['tabela']);
                $STH->bindParam(':4', $_POST['id_tabele']);
                $STH->bindParam(':5', $_POST['naziv']);

                $STH->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";

        }
```

How I can check so if data excist in database to jump to other data, and if data is unique in database to add this data?

I dont want to add duplicate data to my database...
Is it possible with php pdo?

Comment: really sorry for my english...

Comment: Why don't you first run a SELECT query looking for that data? and if it doesn't exist, run the INSERT. It's not like you're limited to only 1 query in total...

Comment: how to do this with php PDO, some example ? is there some other ways ?

Comment: appropriate usage of the unique index comes to mind

Comment: @gmaestro, are you asking how to perform an SQL query using PDO?? The exact same way as you are doing now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is by having the *database* prevent duplicate data going in.  You can do this with a unique index.

Assuming by "unique" you mean all five columns, then the index would be:

```
create unique index track_aktivnosti_5cols on
    track_aktivnosti(datum, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv);
```

Then, when you try to insert data into the table that already exists, you'll get an error.  If you don't want an error, then there are two easy ways to avoid it.  The better is:

```
INSERT INTO track_aktivnosti(datum, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv)
    VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datum = VALUES(datum);
```

This will do a redundant update when it encounters a duplicate value.  This prevents the error.  The other method is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO track_aktivnosti(datum, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv)
    VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5);
```

This will ignore the duplicate error when it occurs (the insert doesn't take place).  But it will ignore all other errors as well.

Comment: I look for this code: create unique index track_aktivnosti_5cols on
    track_aktivnosti(datum, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv); so just this withut chanes insert function work great... but how?